# How to value-initialize aggregate types with list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++14, value-initialization, list-initialization, aggregate-initialization

How can one value-initialize aggregate types in C++14 with the list-intialization syntax?

```
Aggregate_t {};
```

This is seen as aggregate initialization, which produces errors or warnings for uninitialized members of `Aggregate_t`.

Is this possible at all?

**EDIT**: examples

```
struct Aggregate_t {
  int x;
};

int main (int, char**)
{
  Aggregate_t {};
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with g++-4.9.2:

```
main.c++: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.c++:7:16: warning: missing initializer for member ‘Aggregate_t::x’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
   Aggregate_t {};
            ^
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), together with the errors you get.

Comment: This should have the same effect as value-initialization (unless something changed since C++11 - I'm not entirely up-to-date yet). Do you actually get errors, or just over-zealous warnings? Also, please show us the definition of `Aggregate_t` so we can check it really is an aggregate.

Comment: It might be an overzealous warning, but the question is more about the effects of initialization. If uninitialized members of aggregate initialization are value-initialized (according to The Standard), then I guess this is the answer to my question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath except that `{}` does initialize that member.

Comment: I see this as an over-zealous warning, and usually disable it by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[dcl.init.aggr]**:

> 7 - If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized [*C++14*: from its *brace-or-equal-initializer* or, if there is no *brace-or-equal-initializer*,] from an empty initializer list (8.5.4).

So g++ is being overzealous with its warning; I don't know of a way to avoid it while preserving it in cases where the warning is valid, except of course to use copy-initialization with expected copy elision:

```
Aggregate_t a = Aggregate_t();
```

Comment: I also found it in cppreference.com: "If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer clauses is completely empty, the remaining members are initialized by their brace-or-equal initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise by empty lists, which performs value-initialization." So, it generally should have the same effect as value-initializing.

Comment: The point would be not to have to resort to -() syntax to avoid gcc's warnings. Seems like it cannot be done, so, thanks!

Comment: As the name of the warning suggests, `-Wmissing-field-initializers` is for, well, missing initializers—even when the underlying thing is being initialized (as per [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)). It is however designed to have exceptions, empty braces being one of them. In my experience GCC is not very good at this, so I would recommend `-Wno-missing-field-initializers` if you are confident it will not hide mistakes.